# In a nested class in Python what's the best way to access the outer classes parent class?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, nested, inner-classes

I have a non trivial Django system and there's a lot of Meta class inheritance going on. Boiled down to it's essence that looks like this:

```
class Base:
    class Meta:
        pass

class Child(Base):
    class Meta(Base.Meta):  # this
        pass

class GrandChild(Child):
    class Meta(Child.Meta):  # this
        pass
```

The problem with this is it's easy to overlook the lines marked "this" when making changes to the inheritance structure.

This is fundamentally the same problem as with Python2's super requiring the name of the parent class.

And like with that what I'd like is a way of writing those lines in a way that doesn't explicitly reference the outer classes base. Something like:

```
class Base:
    class Meta:
        pass

class Child(Base):
    class Meta(super.Meta):  # this
        pass

class GrandChild(Child):
    class Meta(super.Meta):  # this
        pass
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Not a helpful answer - but this looks like a bit of a crazy pattern you have going on.   Anyway - annoyingly, there isn't an easy way to go from an inner class to and outer class.

Comment: Secondly - a metaclass in python is a specific thing, and this is not it.   Django and SqlAlchemy use an inner class called Meta to store some inner metadata, which is OK - you don't really want to have any logic in the inner classes though, as scope gets tricky, as you are already finding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can tackle the problem with a class factory function

```
def MetaClassFactory(name, SuperClass):
    newclass = type(name, (SuperClass.Meta,), {})
    return newclass


class Base(object):
    class Meta(object):
        someattr = 0

class Child(Base):
    Meta = MetaClassFactory("Meta", Base)

class GrandChild(Child):
    Meta = MetaClassFactory("Meta", Child)

# The class with its attribute is everywhere present (no AttributeError raised)
print "Base: {}, Child: {}, Grandchild: {}".format(Base.Meta.someattr, Child.Meta.someattr, GrandChild.Meta.someattr)

# Override it for Child (Grandchild inherits it)
Child.Meta.someattr = 1
print "Base: {}, Child: {}, Grandchild: {}".format(Base.Meta.someattr, Child.Meta.someattr, GrandChild.Meta.someattr)
```

The two print statements yield:

```
Base: 0, Child: 0, Grandchild: 0
Base: 0, Child: 1, Grandchild: 1
```